# How can I type check a generic then cast to it in swift?

Tags: swift, generics, casting, swift-protocols

I like the ideas [presented in this post](https://www.swiftbysundell.com/posts/separation-of-concerns-using-protocols-in-swift), about making database-agnostic, protocol-oriented code.

So say I have a protocol such as:

```
protocol Database {
    func loadObjects<T>(matching query: Query) -> [T]
    func loadObject<T>(withID id: String) -> T?
    func save<T>(_ object: T)
}
```

where `Query` is a struct that has filter and sort specifiers.

Then, given a persistence framework, such as Realm or CoreData, I can just support this protocol, as such:

```
extension NSManagedObjectContext: Database {
    ...
}

extension Realm: Database {
    ...
}

extension MockedDatabase: Database {
    ...
}

extension UITestingDatabase: Database {
    ...
}
```

The issue arises when I would want to use CoreData.

If we look at the method:

`func loadObjects<T>(matching query: Query) -> [T]`

I have no way to 'cast' T to NSManagedObject.

For example, my desired implementation might be something like:

```
extension NSManagedObjectContext: Database {

    func loadObjects<T>(matching query: Query<T>) -> [T] {

        // you need a fetch request for these models.  This guard statement compiles.  How do we make it work with NSFetchRequestResult however?
        guard T.self is NSManagedObject.Type else {
            return []
        }

        // This line below Fails compiling.  Type 'T' does not conform to protocol 'NSFetchRequestResult'
        var request = NSFetchRequest<T>(entityName: String(describing: T))

        // then set sortDescriptors and predicate, etc.

        var objects: [T] = []
        self.performAndWait {
            do {
                if let results = try self.fetch(request!) as? [T] {
                    objects = results
                }

            } catch let error {
                print("Error fetching: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
        }
        return objects
    }
}
```

So if I can determine if T's Type is a kind of NSManagedObject, then is it possible to instantiate a NSFetchRequest by 'casting' T to something that will work?  It would seem I can't cast or force T to be anything.

Database is a technology-agnostic protocol and therefore shouldn't know anything about Core Data.  I'd like to do this in the event I need to change my data persistence framework.

How might I accomplish this in Swift?  Would I have to add to the `Model` protocol to return optionals that would be used for the given frameworks I would support?  Or make them support NSFetchRequestResult?  I would rather that only the implementation of the protocol need to care about the details of the persistence framework.

Comment: What is `Model`?

Comment: nothing really.  Some basic protocol for models.  Likely just one property var identifier: String

Comment: I'm basing some of the work on this:  https://www.swiftbysundell.com/posts/separation-of-concerns-using-protocols-in-swift

Answer (score 0):

Rather than checking the type at **runtime** constrain the type at **compile time**, for example

```
extension NSManagedObjectContext: Database {

    func loadObjects<T: NSManagedObject>(matching query: Query<T>) -> [T] {

        let request = NSFetchRequest<T>(entityName: String(describing: T.self))

        var objects = [T]()
        self.performAndWait {
            do {
                objects = try self.fetch(request) // a generic fetch request returns an array of the generic type or throws an error
            } catch let error {
                print("Error fetching: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
        }
        return objects
    }
}
```

Comment: The thing is, the protocol method `func loadObjects<T>(...)` should be agnostic and not dependent on CoreData classes.  

Imagine for example, I want my Database protocol to be supported by Realm and not CoreData...

Comment: It's much more efficient to implement 7 methods with 7 different type constraints rather than one method with 7 type checks. Generics is useful if the same method can be called with multiple types without any checks. In your case a protocol with associated types might be more suitable and each database can implement its specific code to retrieve the data.

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean.  Have you got any code that shows what you're talking about?  I'm also wondering if associatedtype is going to be required.

Comment: Generics and protocols (with associated types) are two completely different things but many people equalize them or even mix them up. Here is a simple rule: If multiple types can execute exactly the same code (for example a few methods in `UserDefaults`) use generics otherwise – if multiple types need individual implementations of the code – use protocols with associated types.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like I can answer my own question.  One can further constrain generic types by overloading them, so that the calling code can remain the same, but *what* gets called is dependent on the type you pass into it.

This code below demonstrates this in a playground:

```
public protocol Action {
    func doSomething<T>(to object: T)
}

public class MyActor {

}

extension MyActor: Action {

    // works for any type
    public func doSomething<T>(to object: T) {
        print("was generic")
    }

    // but if you constrain the type and your object fits that constraint...
    // this code is called (same method signature)
    public func doSomething<T: NSObject>(to object: T) {
        print("was an object")
    }
}

class MyObject: NSObject {
    var name: String = "Object"
}

struct MyStruct {
    var name: String = "Struct"
}

let actor = MyActor()
let object = MyObject()
let value = MyStruct()

actor.doSomething(to: value) // prints 'was generic'
actor.doSomething(to: object)  // prints 'was an object'
```

So in the original example, I would then support `Database` for CoreData with:

```
extension NSManagedObjectContext: Database {

    func loadObjects<T>(matching query: Query<T>) -> [T] {
       return [] // return an empty array because we only support NSManagedObject types
    }

    func loadObjects<T: NSManagedObject>(matching query: Query<T>) -> [T] {

        let request = NSFetchRequest<T>(entityName: String(describing: T.self))

        var objects = [T]()
        self.performAndWait {
            do {
                objects = try self.fetch(request) // a generic fetch request returns an array of the generic type or throws an error
            } catch let error {
                print("Error fetching: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
        }
        return objects
    }
}
```